# How is created a jar in maven?

Tags: java, xml, maven, maven-plugin

We start from the end, after the build **install**, in the **target** folder, is possibile to see 2 important thing: the **file** producted from the build (war, ear, jar) and a **folder** called usually like the project. My question is, the file is done from the folder ? Or the folder is just a copy to see faster the result of the build ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical build, maven places in  `target/generated_folder` all required builds assets(compiled classes, resources e.t.c).

Then, depending on the declared packaging, compresses aforesaid folder and generates the final artifact.

So to answer you question, the final generated file is derived from the folder inside `target` directory.

Comment: so why if I add a folder with the ant-run-plugin inside target/generated_folder I don't find It inside the ear (for example)

Comment: That's another question, maven has phases and phases have goals. It is possible that you execute antrun plugin in wrong phase/goal. Anyway, if you face such an issue I would recommend to post a new question.

Comment: @Storm Also, on your comment's example, in order to add folder to ear, you can configure `maven-ear-plugin` accordingly.